# How to copy or convert an Int[] array into a var in a JSP page

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, web-applications

I have a JSP page to which I sent some parameters, including an array of int[]; after some operations, this array is filled with some numbers.
Also inside this JSP page, there's a script in which I declare an array like this:

```
<script>
   var matrix = [];

...
</script>
```

What I need is to copy or convert my int[] array into the var matrix, how could I do this kind of operation? Could you share me the code necessary for this purpose?

I tried to do

```
<script>
   var matrix = [];
   matrix = <%= myArray%>

...
</script>
```

Where myArray is the

```
int[] myArray = new int[length];
```

But it didn't work.
I hope I have provided all the necessary information, if you need more information don't hesitate to ask, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
  <script>
   var matrix = [];
   <% for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) { %>
     matrix[<%= i %>] = <%= myArray[i] %>; //without the apices
   <% } %>

   ...
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works :-) I make a small correction, I remove the apices matrix[<%= i %>] = <%= myArray[i] %>;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
   var matrix = <%= java.util.Arrays.toString(myArray)%>
</script>
```